# pyFlask is putting my inputs in my url browser

Tags: python, html, flask

Briefly, python Flask is the workbench of web hosting I use, and I am trying to create an input form that doesn't appear in your history.

This is my form html:

```html
<form name="ViewWindow" action="/home/ViewWindow/ViewWindowResult/">
  <input name="url" type="url" required="required" placeholder="URL Here">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

And this is the python code working with the input *url*:

```py
@web_site.route('/home/ViewWindow/ViewWindowResult/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def ViewWindowResult():
  urlboi = request.values.get('url')

  response = urllibrequest.urlopen(url) # import urllib.request as urllibrequest
  htmlBytes = response.read()
  htmlstr = htmlBytes.decode("utf8")

  return html("ViewWindowResult.html", value=htmlstr)
```

My goal is to get here; `/home/ViewWindow/ViewWindow/ViewWindowResult/`,
but I end up getting here when I input "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/"; `/home/ViewWindow/ViewWindowResult/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Ftags%2F`

#### Why does Flask put my inputs in the url string? I do not intend to do this anywhere.

Edit: You can check this out by going to https://sm--supermechm500.repl.co/home/ViewWindow/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the form method like so:

```
<form name="ViewWindow" action="/home/ViewWindow/ViewWindowResult/" method="post">
  <input name="url" type="url" required="required" placeholder="URL Here">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: I think I did this before but I had accidentally deleted it and forgot what it did. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

use post method like

```
    <form name="ViewWindow" action="/home/ViewWindow/ViewWindowResult/" method="post">
  <input name="url" type="url" required="required" placeholder="URL Here">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form
```

and then you python code is

```
   @web_site.route('/home/ViewWindow/ViewWindowResult/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def ViewWindowResult():
  input=request.form['url']
#write your code here
return(input)
```

its working for me it will print the url which same you entered